# Show $A\in L(E,F) \iff \forall f\in F^{*} \; f \circ A \in E^{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show $A\in L(E,F) \iff \forall f\in F^{*} \; f \circ A \in E^{*}$. The book actually show the left-direction implication, but the right-direction just says "this is obvious".

I'm guessing it actually is obvious, but I'm not seeing it yet.

$A \in L(E,F)$ means $A:E \to F$ is continuous/bounded. $f \in F^{*}$ means $f$ is a continuous linear functional $f:F^{*} \times F \to R:\langle f,x\rangle = f(x)$.

I am not connecting the definitions for why the right implication should be true though. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The composition of

- continuous maps is continuous
- linear maps is linear

Note that $f\in F^*$ means $f$ is a continuous linear map $F\to\mathbb{R}$, not a map $F^*\times F\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you and Tom for the Answers. Both explain it well. In my book it says "Given $f \in E^{*}$ and $x\in E$ we shall often write \langle f,x\rangle instead of $f(x)$; we say that $\langle , \rangle$ is the $\textit{scalar product for the duality}$ $E^{*},E$." Isn't that what we have? The dual space $F^{*}$ and the space $F$ ?

Comment: @Taln That's just alternative notation for $f(x)$. By definition $F^*$ consists of the continuous linear maps $F\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for you help! Do you know by what properties, in Tom's Answer, we are allowed to do the decomposition into inequalities in the second bullet point? I don't know why that is true.

Comment: @Taln By definition of operator norm, $\|A(x)\|\le\|A\|\,\|x\|$. But it's not needed: just standard continuity arguments apply.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \in L(E,F)$ and $f \in F^{\ast}$, then

- $f \circ A(x+\lambda y)  = f( Ax + \lambda Ay) = f\circ A(x) + \lambda f \circ A (y)$

  $\| f\circ A(x)\| \leq \|f\|\, \|A(x)\| \leq \|f\|\,\|A\|\,\|x\|$ implying $\|f \circ A\| \leq \|f \| \, \|A\|$.

Comment: Tom, you meant to write $f \in F^{*}$ right?

Comment: Also Tom can you explain by what property we are allowed to decompose $||f \circ A(x)||$ into the rest of those inequalities? Thanks!

Comment: @Taln  You are correct, $f \in F^{\ast}$. Also, you know that for any $y \in F$, $|f(y)| \leq \| f\|\, \|y\|$ where $\|f\|$ means the operator norm of $f$. Now, set $y = Ax$, so you have $|f(y)| \leq \|f\|\, \|y\| = \|f\|\,\|Ax\|$. From here know that $\|Ax \| \leq \|A\|\,\|x\|$ (again, $\|A\|$ refers to the operator norm of $A$) and so you arrive at $\|f\|\,\|Ax\|\leq \|f\|\,\|A\|\,\|x\|$.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I understand now.